# bash - How to append to a sed command with a regex wildcard

Tags: search, awk, sed, append

I'm new to using regex and bash scripts.

I have a file (map.txt) which has contents similar to (there are more headers but they all start with '[DATABASE-*]:

```
[DATABASE-WRITE-SPEED]
source=DATABASE-WRITE

[DATABASE-READ-IOPS]

[DATABASE-QUERY-LONG]
```

I also have another file which has a list of server names (server.csv) such as:

```
Server Name

Server1

Server2

Server3
```

I want to use a sed command that can find the headers in map.txt (i.e. [DATABASE-QUERY-LONG]) and add the Server Name

For example:

```
[DATABASE-WRITE-SPEED-Server1]
[DATABASE-READ-IOPS-Server1]
[DATABASE-QUERY-LONG-Server1]

[DATABASE-WRITE-SPEED-Server2]
[DATABASE-READ-IOPS-Server2]
[DATABASE-QUERY-LONG-Server2]

[DATABASE-WRITE-SPEED-Server3]
[DATABASE-READ-IOPS-Server3]
[DATABASE-QUERY-LONG-Server3]
```

So far, I have a sed command but it doesn't keep the contents of the searched result whilst appending the server name:

```
for i in $(awk 'NR>1 {print $2}' server.csv); do
    sed s/\\[DATABASE-.*]/[DATABASE-.* $i]/g map.txt
done
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Isn't this what capture groups are for?

Comment: @Barmar - or `&` if you're using sed.   But this fundamentally looks like a shell question.  OP is basically done except that I don't see double quotes.  `sed "/\[DATABASE/s/]/$i]/" map.txt`

Comment: @stevesliva `&` is only useful if you want to copy the entire match, but he needs to copy just part of the match.

Comment: @Barmar - `s/\[DATABASE[^\]]*/& $1/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a capture group to copy part of the match into the replacement.

Also, you should quote the `sed` expression since it contains wildcard characters and other characters with special meaning to the shell.

```
sed "s/\\[(DATABASE-.*)\\]/[\\1-$i]/g" map.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

IMHO `awk` should be perfect suit for this one, could you please try following.

```
awk '
FNR==NR && NF && /^\[DATABASE/{
  sub(/\]$/,"")
  a[++count]=$0
  next
}
FNR>1 && NF && FNR!=NR{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    print a[i]"-"$0"]"
  }
}
' map.txt server.csv
```

Explanation:

```
awk '                                ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR && NF && /^\[DATABASE/{      ##Checking condition if FNR==NR AND NF is not null AND line is having string DATABASE in it then do following.
  sub(/\]$/,"")                      ##Using substitute option to perform substitution of ] at last of line with NULL.
  a[++count]=$0                      ##Creating an array a whose index is variable count value increment with 1 each time it coms here and value is $0.
  next                               ##next will skip all statements from here.
}                                    ##Closing BLOCK for this condition now.
FNR>1 && NF && FNR!=NR{              ##Checking condition FNR>1 AND number of fields is NOT NULL AND FNR!=NR which means it should run for 2nd Input_file only.
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){             ##Running a for loop from i=1 to till value of variable count here.
    print a[i]"-"$0"]"               ##Printing value of array a with index of variable i dash and current line ] here.
  }                                  ##Closing BLOCK for, for loop here.
}                                    ##Closing BLOCK for 2nd condition here.
'  map.txt server.csv                ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```